# Binding Multiple item to listview row

Tags: c#, wpf

Here is a description of what I'am trying to do: I need to build a catalog of products that when a user press's the meat buttong the catalog (ListView) fills up with pics of meat i want each row to contain 3 products...Heres what I have so far:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ImageConverter x:Key="ImageConverter"/>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="imageListView">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="{Binding .,Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" Height="50" Width="100" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ImageCollection}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource imageListView}"/>    
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Back Code For XAML:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyViewModel VM = new MyViewModel();
        DataContext = VM;
    }
}

class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is Bitmap)
            return ConvertBitmapToBitmapImage((Bitmap)value);
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }

    private BitmapImage ConvertBitmapToBitmapImage(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        bitmap.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.BeginInit();
        bitmapImage.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(memoryStream.ToArray());
        bitmapImage.EndInit();
        return bitmapImage;
    }
}
```

And MyViewModel Code:

```
private List<Bitmap> m_ImageCollection;
public MyViewModel()
{
    LoadImages();  
}
void LoadImages()
{
    m_ImageCollection = new List<Bitmap>();
    ResourceManager rm = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager;
    ResourceSet rs = rm.GetResourceSet(new CultureInfo("en-US"), true, true);
    if (rs != null)
    {
        var images =
          from entry in rs.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
          where entry.Value is Bitmap
          select entry;

        foreach (DictionaryEntry img in images)
        {
            if (img.Value is Bitmap)
                m_ImageCollection.Add((Bitmap)img.Value);
        }
    }
}
public List<Bitmap> ImageCollection
{
    get { return m_ImageCollection; }    
    set { m_ImageCollection = value; }
}
```

The Picturs are loading but each picture in a row I want three pictures in a row...

Any Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just make a VM that represents a row:

```
    //immutable - so safe to bind to without INotifyPropertyChange support
    public sealed class BitmapRow
    {
            private readonly Bitmap _bitmap1;
            private readonly Bitmap _bitmap2;
            private readonly Bitmap _bitmap3;

            public BitmapRow(Bitmap bitmap1, Bitmap bitmap2, Bitmap bitmap3)
            {
                _bitmap1 = bitmap1;
                _bitmap2 = bitmap2;
                _bitmap3 = bitmap3;
            }

            public Bitmap Bitmap1{ get{return _bitmap1;}}
            public Bitmap Bitmap2{ get{return _bitmap2;}}
            public Bitmap Bitmap3{ get{return _bitmap3;}}
    }
```

Then:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  <Image Source="{Binding Path=Bitmap1,Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" Height="50" Width="100" />
  <Image Source="{Binding Path=Bitmap2,Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" Height="50" Width="100" />
  <Image Source="{Binding Path=Bitmap3,Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" Height="50" Width="100" />
</StackPanel>
```

Changes to main VM then look like: (by the way `List<T>` is not a good idea for WPF, use `ObservableCollection<T>`):

```
    private readonly ObservableCollection<BitmapRow> m_ImageCollection = new ObservableCollection<BitmapRow>();
    public IEnumerable<BitmapRow> ImageCollection
    {
        get { return m_ImageCollection; }
    }

    void LoadImages()
    {            
        ResourceManager rm = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager;
        ResourceSet rs = rm.GetResourceSet(new CultureInfo("en-US"), true, true);
        if (rs != null)
        {
            //var allImages = new List<Bitmap>();
            //var images =
            //  from entry in rs.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
            //  where entry.Value is Bitmap
            //  select entry;                

            //foreach (DictionaryEntry img in images)
            //{
            //    var bmp = img.Value as Bitmap; //one type cast
            //    if (bmp!=null)
            //    {
            //        allImages.Add(bmp);
            //    }
            //}

            //neat alternative to all of above code:
            var allImages = rs.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().Values.OfType<Bitmap>().ToList();
            //or maybe you need to do this:
            var allImages = rs.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().Select(d=>d.Value).OfType<Bitmap>().ToList();

            //now load the images in allImages in 3s into BitmapRows and add to m_ImageCollection 
            //I'll leave this bit up to you to complete - you need to decide what to do
            //when the list is not an exact multiple of 3
            var max = allImages.Count();
            for(ini row = 0; row < max/3; row+=1)
            {
               Bitmap a = allImages[row*3];
               Bitmap b = allImages[row*3+1]; //TODO: needs index checking
               Bitmap c = allImages[row*3+2]; //TODO: needs index checking
               m_ImageCollection.Add(new BitmapRow(a,b,c));
            }
        }
    }
```